# Paste as new table

Tags: microsoft-access

When I highlight a set of records from, for example, a query or a filtered table, I can copy these and paste them into an existing table.

Is it possible to paste them and, in doing so, create a new table?

Comment: Yes you can just try it

Comment: @yass And create a brand new table? I'm not sure how to do this?

Comment: "paste them and, in doing so, create a new table?" - paste them where? I'm afraid it's not going to work. You can paste it e.g. to Excel / notepad, then import that file to a new table.

Comment: Create a new empty Table in Access and paste the copied record to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to create an empty New table in Access no need to design it, just create a new table
Open the query or the filtered table, select the records you need to copy and copy.
Open the empty New Table you already created and paste the records in it.
You will have The copied records in a new Table.